# Show alert in bot with python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

in a telegram bot written with python-telegram-bot, I have some keyboard buttons and, when I click on one of them, I would like an alert to be shown, like here:
[alert screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGRHX.png)

However, it doesn't do anything when I click on the buttons and I can't figure out what's wrong.
Thank you!

Below my code:

````
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater,
    CommandHandler,
    CallbackQueryHandler,
)


token = 'XXX'
updater = Updater(token=token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


def start(update, context):
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("dog", callback_data='dog'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("cat", callback_data='cat'),
        ],
    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
        text=f'Hello {update.message.chat.first_name}!',
        reply_markup=reply_markup,
    )


def buttons(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query

    query.answer()

    if query.data == 'cat':
        context.bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=query.id, text='you chose cat', show_alert=True)
    elif query.data == 'dog':
        context.bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=query.id, text='you chose dog', show_alert=True)


start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)

buttons_handler = CallbackQueryHandler(buttons)
dispatcher.add_handler(buttons_handler)


updater.start_polling()```
````

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you get in variables and which part of code is executed. OR learn how to use debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove `query.answer()` and send it only when you don't want to send alert

```
def buttons(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query

    # query.answer() # <-- move it to `else:`

    if query.data == 'cat':
        context.bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=query.id, text='you chose cat', show_alert=True)
    elif query.data == 'dog':
        context.bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=query.id, text='you chose dog', show_alert=True)
    else:
        query.answer() # <-- send it only when you have no alert
```

or more readable

```
def buttons(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query

    if query.data == 'cat':
        query.answer(text='you chose cat', show_alert=True)
    elif query.data == 'dog':
        query.answer(text='you chose dog', show_alert=True)
    else:
        query.answer()
```

---

My code for test - I had to add `updater.idle()` to keep it running.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater,
    CommandHandler,
    CallbackQueryHandler,
)

token = 'MY_TOKEN'
updater = Updater(token=token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


def start(update, context):
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("dog", callback_data='dog'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("cat", callback_data='cat'),
        ],
    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

#    context.bot.send_message(
#        chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
#        text=f'Hello {update.message.chat.first_name}!',
#        reply_markup=reply_markup,
#    )

    update.message.reply_text(f'Hello {update.message.chat.first_name}!', reply_markup=reply_markup)


def buttons(update, context):
    logger.info('Update: "%s"\nContext: "%s"', update, context.error)

    query = update.callback_query

    # query.answer() # <-- move it to `else`

    if query.data == 'cat':
        #context.bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=query.id, text='you chose cat', show_alert=True)
        query.answer(text='you chose cat!', show_alert=True)
    elif query.data == 'dog':
        #context.bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=query.id, text='you chose dog', show_alert=True)
        query.answer(text='you chose dog!', show_alert=True)
    else:
        query.answer('nothing')


start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)

buttons_handler = CallbackQueryHandler(buttons)
dispatcher.add_handler(buttons_handler)

updater.start_polling()
print('Running... [Press Ctrl+C to stop]')
updater.idle() # need to keep running
```